# Using a Typescript Generic with simple addition isn't working

Tags: typescript

This seems so trivial, yet I am not understanding why this isn't working. Since I am just concatinating/adding depending on a number or string, the return type should match.

```
function M<T>(arg: T): T {
  return arg + arg;
}


M(3) // 6
M('bill') // billbill
```

Comment: What did you want? `const a = M<number>(3); // a will be a number`, `const b = M<string>('bill');// b will be a string`

Comment: See also this issue on the topic https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12410

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no type constraint in TypeScript saying a certain operator can be applied to a certain type. So it is not possible to do this.

Something close and valid is:

```
interface Addable<T> {
    add(that: T): T;
}

function M<T extends Addable<T>>(arg: T): T {
  return arg.add(arg);
}
```

But there is just no way to express it for an operator, `+` in this case.

Comment: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html , doesn't seem to work when used with: M(3) or M(test)

Comment: @jamesemanon Certainly it doesn’t. There’s just no way to do that.